# Response for Form with custom action using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, carrierwave

I want to upload the user avatar (carrierwave) using a **custom action** like this:

```
= form_for user, url: update_user_avatar_path(id: user.id), :html => {:class => "up-cl-ava-form", data: {type: :json}, novalidate: true, method: :put}, remote: true do |f|
        = f.file_field :avatar_picture
        = f.submit "Update", remote: true
```

In **UsersController**

```
def update_user_avatar
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) || current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes!(avatar_picture: params[:user][:avatar_picture])
        format.json { render json: {}, status: :ok}
      else
        format.json { render json: {}, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
```

**Params** in #update_user_avatar

> {"utf8"=>"✓",  "_method"=>"put", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"BPGeN5mpRCYwIco1YSsBx6IT7MfIBOdSlwS9Y5WJZeU=", 
>   "user"=>   {"avatar_picture"=>
>       #>},  "commit"=>"Update",  "id"=>"30",  "action"=>"update_user_avatar",
>   "controller"=>"users"}

**Request**

> .... "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvz51HFYrromiuTS7" ....

**In my JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".up-cl-ava-form").on("ajax:success", function(){
      alert("success")
    });

  });
```

The problem here is that the image is uploaded correctly but the site redirects to **lvh.me:3000/update_user_avatar?id=30** (blank page), *instead staying in the same view.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be solve by adding  `remotipart` gem

https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

Comment: This is I was looking for. **Jquery UJS does not supports remote file uploads**